# Code to autofill x number of rows based on a value from another cell

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

I have a macro which will autofill a sheet down a number of rows based on a value in another cell.

My code is as below. At the moment it will only autofill the series down to the row number of the value in the reference cell. (basically if I have the number 40 on the referenced cell, the code autofills down to row 40 and not down 40 rows which is what I need).

Wondering if someone could help me here.

```
    Range("A8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A8:A" & Range("J1").Value), Type:=xlFillSeries
    Range("A8:A104").Select
```

This is part of the code, the code before copies some other info into the sheet.

Comment: If you are always going to start from A8 and you want to fill the next X rows you can do a quick dirty +8 and it will do what you ask, if you put 20, it will do the next 20 rows, if you do 30, it will do the next 30 rows: Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A8:A" & Range("J1").Value + 8), Type:=xlFillSeries

Comment: Ricardo - see below Olly gave me some code which fitted most easily with my existing code and it worked a treat - thanks for comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`Range("A8").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A8").Resize(Range("J1").Value,1), Type:=xlFillSeries`

Comment: Olly - this was the simplest option for me to try with the other code I had - many thanks as this worked an absolute treat.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    With ActiveSheet
       AutoFillRange .Range("A8"), Range("J1").Value
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub AutoFillRange(ByVal startCell As Range, ByVal numberOfRows As Long)
    startCell.AutoFill Destination:=startCell.Parent.Range(startCell, startCell.Offset(numberOfRows - 1)), Type:=xlFillSeries
End Sub
```

Comment: QHarr - Olly below bave me some code which fitted more easily with the code I had in place, thankfully it worked a treat.  As such I didn't try out your code, but can keep for another day.  Thanks for the efforts.

Comment: No worries. The advantage of the above, for later use, is that you can re-use the same sub (AutoFillRange) with different start cell and different cell to use for row count.